# What is the difference between a variable and a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, parameters

I am learning python 3 and programming in general for the first time, but I can't seem to distinguish a parameter and a variable?

Comment: Parameters are things passed to functions `foo(parameter)`. Variables are assigned within the code `a = 2`

Comment: If by parameter you mean function arguments, then parameter is a variable that has a lifetime only within one function call, and this variable is assigned a value that was inside `()` of function call. So parameter is also a variable.

Comment: I find it interesting that the answer to this question already exists in the description of the two tags, [tag:variables] and [tag:parameters]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable is just something that refers/points to some data you have.

```
x = 5
```

Here x is a variable. Variables can point to more kinds of data than just numbers, though. They can point to strings, functions, etc.

A parameter is something that is passed into a function

```
def my_function(y):
    print(y)
```

Here y is a parameter. It doesn't contain a value yet. But if I want to call the function, I need to provide an argument to the function.

An argument is the actual value you provide to the function that replaces the parameter.

```
my_function(5)
```

Here, 5 is the argument. Of course, since x points to the value "5", I can do this too:

```
my_function(x)
```

which also prints 5

Comment: 'y' doesn't contain a value? Actually it does. Actually it behaves just like any other variable except that it is assigned a copy of the value used in making the call.

Comment: It doesn't contain a value when you initially define the function. Of course, when you call the function, the argument is passed and now the parameter, y, has the value 5. Also, the phrase I used "replace the parameter" is not quite accurate since that is not how python passes arguments, and the parameter is a variable in the method scope, but for the sake of beginner understanding, I think it is fine.

Answer (score 9):

A parameter is a variable that was received as an argument to a function. Once the function has begun executing, the parameter is just like any other variable; it can be reassigned (and stops being tied to the caller's argument) like anything else.

```
 global_variable = ... still a variable, just defined globally ...
 def foo(parameter):
     function_local_variable = ... something defined locally ...


 foo(... argument that is bound to parameter in foo ...)
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the *currently* accepted answer.

Comment: @Booboo: Thanks! I'll admit to be fairly lazy with the distinction between parameter and argument normally; is it better or worse if I know better and (on this one topic, and only this one topic) choose not to be pedantic about it? :-)

Answer (score 2):

A parameter is a type of variable that serves as the input to a method.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is a name (identifier) that refers to some value. Values can be either immutable types, that is, types that cannot be changed such as strings, bytes, integers and floating point numbers:

```
x = 5 # immutable type
y = x # y points to what x currently points to, namely 5
x = 9 # x points to a new value, 9
print(x, y) # 9 5
```

A variable can also name a mutable type:

```
class MyType:
    pass

t1 = MyType()
t1.x = 5 # set member x to 5
t2 = t1 # t2 points to the same object as t1
t1.x = 9
print(t1.x, t2.x) # 9 9
```

A parameter (or argument) is a value passed to a function:

```
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo(some_value)
```

`x` is an argument to function `foo`. `foo(some_value)` invokes function `foo` with the value `some_value` as the actual value. The Python interpreter implicitly assigns `x = some_value` at the entry to function `foo`. Note that `x` is a variable is every sense of the word but that it is defined in the scope of `foo` so that it hides any other definition of `x` that may exist outside of `foo`.